# magento 2, change label in order creation page in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, sales-order

I appreciate any hint on how to change the "Email" label in order creation page in admin panel (I have created a module to override the `vendor/magento/module-sales` templates, so no issue with this part)

[image]

Considering below in `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form/account.phtml` where this label is set? I could not find the `getForm()->getHtml()`!

```
<div class="admin__page-section-title <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHeaderCssClass() ?>">
    <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getHeaderText() ?></span>
    <div class="actions"></div>
</div>
<div id="customer_account_fieds" class="admin__page-section-content">
    <?php echo $block->getForm()->getHtml() ?>
</div>

<script>
    require(["prototype", "Magento_Sales/order/create/form"], function(){
        order.accountFieldsBind($('customer_account_fieds'));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create your own admin theme and change the field here:
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml` line 133

Comment: Through my module I'm going to override the core module-sales templates but the path you are mentioning is targetting the order view page not creation page! But thanks